# Pandas - Edit Index using pattern / regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

Given a data frame like:

```
>>> df
      ix  val1  val2  val3  val4
    1.31     2     3     4     5
    8.22     2     3     4     5
    5.39     2     3     4     5
    7.34     2     3     4     5
```

Is it possible to edit index using something like [replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)?

Pseudo code: (since df index doesnt have str attribute)

```
df.index=df.index.str.replace("\\.[0-9]*","")
```

I need something like:

```
>>> df
   ix  val1  val2  val3  val4
    1     2     3     4     5
    8     2     3     4     5
    5     2     3     4     5
    7     2     3     4     5
```

The problem is that my dataframe is huge.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
df.index = df.index.to_series().astype(str).str.replace(r'\.[0-9]*','').astype(int)
```

you may also use `.extract`:

```
df.index.to_series().astype(str).str.extract(r'(\d+)').astype(int)
```

alternatively, you may just `map` the index to `int`:

```
pd.Index(map(int, df.index))
```

Comment: Thank you behzad.nouri. That did the job !